# Run Thread Until 2 Integers are the Same

Tags: java, java-threads, background-thread

I want to check in the background if 2 Integers are the same. When they are the same I want the thread to stop and I want one of my function to be called. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be useful to see what you've attempted so far as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make an assumption here that you know how to setup and execute java threads in the background. In your runnable, when defining your run() function you can setup a while true loop which then compares the value of the two numbers and breaks the loop if they are equal. if they are not equal it sleeps for x milliseconds before it loops. After the loop you call the function you wanted to call if the values were equal. It should look like this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if(a == b){
            break;
        }
         Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    myfunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!runnable.interrupted()) {
           if( varOne.equals(varTwo)) {
               yourFn();
            runnable.interrupted();
           } else {
               //Do nothing.
           }
        }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```